# Quartz scheduler misfire changes the subsequent execution time

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Here is the situation:

- There is an hourly job scheduled from 09:00.
- System goes down for some reason. Till 11:15.
- The misfire policy configured is: MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_RESCHEDULE_NOW_WITH_REMAINING_REPEAT_COUNT
- System comes back at 11:15, due to the misfire, it will start the job.
- Now all the subsequent jobs run with the additional 15 delay like 12:15, 13:15, 14:15 ...

How can I prevent this additional delay in the subsequent jobs?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using a simple or cron trigger? can you try using a cron trigger?

Comment: Yes. I am using simple trigger. We take the input from the user in date object as start time and then frequency in minutes. I will check cron trigger can support this. Thanks for inputs.

Comment: Use CronTrigger. "0 0 * * * ?" will fire trigger every hour, on the hour.